# Javascript Array generated by ASP Repeater not updated

Tags: javascript, asp.net, arrays, google-maps, repeater

I have a repeater to generate an array(for google map marker) in client side javascript. It works fine on first load but when I trigger a post back and bind the repeater with other data. The repeater will return the initial array value to my variable. Is there any way going wrong? please help

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  Var markers = [];
    function LoadMarker() {
    markers = [];
    var data =[
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptMarkers" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
                {
                "title": '<%# Eval("DeviceName") %>',
                "lat": '<%# Eval("Latitude") %>',
                "lng": '<%# Eval("Longitude") %>',
                "Origlat": '<%# Eval("OrigLatitude") %>',
                "Origlng": '<%# Eval("OrigLongitude") %>',
                "description": '<%# Eval("Description") %>',
                "Status": '<%# Eval("Status") %>',
                "Active": '<%# Eval("Active") %>'
            }
    </ItemTemplate>
    <SeparatorTemplate>
        ,
    </SeparatorTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>];
    markers = data;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repeater does not work for me but I found an alternative. From code behind serialize dataset with JavaScriptSerializer. Then parse it into a hiddenfield to be accessible by client side code.

HTML

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfSortOrder" runat="server" />
```

JS

```
var markers = [];
markers = JSON.parse(document.get`enter code here`ElementById('<%= hfDummy.ClientID%>').value);
for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
var data = markers[i]
//Do your stuff etc: var info = data.column1
}
```

VB.NET

```
    Dim dsdata As New DataSet
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Dim serializer As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
    Dim rows As New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))()
    Dim row As Dictionary(Of String, Object)

dsdata = ReadData()            

For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
row = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)()
   For Each col As DataColumn In dt.Columns
      row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr(col))
   Next
rows.Add(row)
Next
hfDummy.Value = serializer.Serialize(rows)
```